# Informix irregular timeseries table return wrong result

Tags: database, informix

I am a beginner in informix database, we want to use the irregular timeseries table to store value, but the table return wrong result after it is created, we can not found any solution, can anybody help to take a look?

our informix version is v12, platform is windows server 2012 r2.

below is our step:

```
---create the db space---
onspaces -c -d justtest_dbspace -p  E:\IBM\Informix\12.10\INFORMIX_DWH\dbspaces\ts_testTable.000 -o 30000 -s 30000
```

```
---create the row type---
create row type rw_justtest_row (
    timestamp datetime year to fraction(5),
    gas_code                VARCHAR(20),
    avg_concentration       FLOAT,
    standard_name           VARCHAR(50),
    threshold               FLOAT,
    modified_date           DATETIME year to second,
    text1                   VARCHAR(50),  -- Reserved columns
    text2                   VARCHAR(50), -- Reserved columns
    numeric1                FLOAT, -- Reserved columns
    numeric2                FLOAT  -- Reserved columns
);
```

```
----create the timeserie table
create table rw_justtest_table (
    station_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    subdomain_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    sensor_parameter_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    period                  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    raw_9seconds_irr TIMESERIES(rw_justtest_row)
)
lock mode row;
```

```
---create container
execute procedure TSContainerCreate('container_justtest', 'justtest_dbspace', 'rw_justtest_row', 30000, 30000);
```

```
---insert the calendar
INSERT INTO CalendarTable(c_name, c_calendar)
VALUES('ts_1sec',
'startdate(2022-06-17 00:00:00.00000),pattern({1 on}, second)');
```

```
---creatre the view table
execute procedure TSCreateVirtualTab('rw_justtest_table_v', 'rw_justtest_table', 
    'origin(2022-06-17 00:00:00.00000), calendar(ts_1sec), container(container_justtest), threshold(0), irregular');
```

```
---insert one reoard in side    
insert into rw_justtest_table_v (station_id,subdomain_id,sensor_parameter_code, timestamp, gas_code, avg_concentration, standard_name, period, threshold) values
    ('YL', 'ABCDEFG','ABCDE','2022-06-17 16:00:00','ABCDE','0.222','FIGKL','60','0.09');
```

```
----check the count is 1
select count(*) from informix.rw_justtest_table_v where timestamp >= '2002-06-17 16:00:00';
```

```
---do the select to verify  
select rowid,* from informix.rw_justtest_table_v where timestamp = '2022-06-17 16:00:00';
```

```
---this is the issue, below the query should not be return value, but it is still return and the timestamp is   '2022-06-18 16:00:00'
select rowid,* from informix.rw_justtest_table_v where timestamp = '2022-06-18 16:00:00';
```

The issues is wrong result return, actually I am inserted one record only, the timestamp only '2022-06-17 16:00:00', but when I do the search for '2022-06-18 16:00:00', it is still return value and the result is wrong one. can someone expert help me?

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using, and which platform are you using it on?

Comment: our informix version is v12, platform is windows server 2012 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the behavior of the virtual table for an irregular timeseries.

From the online documentation ( [Irregular time series](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=concepts-irregular-time-series) ):

> Irregular elements persist until the next element by default and
> cannot be null. For example, if you query for the value of a stock
> price at noon but the last recorded trade was at 11:59 AM, the query
> returns the value of the price at 11:59 AM, because that value is the
> nearest value equal to or earlier than noon. However, you can also
> create a query to return null if the specified time stamp does not
> exactly match the time stamp of an element. For example, if you query
> for the price that a stock traded for at noon, but the stock did not
> have a trade at noon, the query returns a null value.

I do not know how to do the query to only return when there is a value for an exact timestamp, but on the definition of the virtual table you can declare the following ( [The TSVTMode parameter](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=data-tsvtmode-parameter#ids_tms_108) ):

> Whether data selected by time stamp exactly matches the specified time
> stamps or includes the last rows that are equal to or earlier than the
> specified time stamps.

> scan_discreet
>
> 1024
>
> (0x000400)    When you select data from a virtual table by time stamps,
> only rows whose time stamps are exactly equal to the time stamps
> specified in the query are returned.

So, when you define the virtual table, you add an extra parameter:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE TSCreateVirtualTab(
    'rw_justtest_table_v', 
    'rw_justtest_table', 
    'origin(2022-06-17 00:00:00.00000), calendar(ts_1sec), container(container_justtest), threshold(0), irregular',
    'scan_discreet');
```

Recreating the virtual table in that way, the query:

`select rowid,* from informix.rw_justtest_table_v where timestamp = '2022-06-18 16:00:00'`;

no longer returns any rows ( using your test case ).